# Is C++11 (C++0x) a complete super set of C++03?

Tags: c++, c++11

`C++` considered (almost) super set of `C`; but still there are certain things which works in `C` and not in `C++`.

Is there any feature/facility which is a valid `C++03` but not working in `C++11` ?

Comment: What works in c but does not work in c++? Or do you mean it has another meaning in c++?

Comment: c is not considered as a super set of C. Tell it to C fans :)

Comment: @RedX, e.g. implicit typecasting, variable length array, etc.

Comment: @Johannes ah yes! new keywords :-)

Comment: `int class = 42; auto int decltype[class];`

Comment: Keywords are the easy ones. There's real language features and definitions that differ too, like those mentioned by @iammilind.

Comment: @iammilind: VLAs aren't really relevant because they came _after_ the C that C++ was borne out of. However, of the C standard that C++ inherits, yes you're right there are things that prohibit "superset" from being an accurate term. Implicit typecasting is a big one.

Comment: C++11 picked up quite a few C99 additions, so VLAs seem reasonable. Either way, the C compatability changes are easy since the C++ standard devotes a chapter to enumerating them.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Is there any feature/facility which is
>   a valid C++03 but not working in C++11
>   ?

There are few incompabilities :

- `export template` is removed (not deprecated, really removed)
- you can't use `auto` as storage specifier anymore
- there are new reserved words : `alignof`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`, `constexpr`, `decltype`, `noexcept`, `nullptr`, `static_assert` and `thread_local`

also, for future versions :

- `std::auto_ptr` is deprecated
- throw specifications are deprecated

Maybe I'm missing others, but if your code uses those, you'll have to fix it.

Almost all C++2003 features still are the same or are more precisely specified for compiler implementations in C++2011.

Comment: Was'nt std::auto_ptr part of TR1 and not the standard implementation?

Comment: AFAIK all TR1 stuff but auto_ptr are integrated in C++2011. TR1 is kind of standard, it's suggestions but standard suggestion so if you use compilers providing TR1 libraries you use, they should act the same.

Comment: @Klaim: and there are the new reserved words too, looking at http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/keywords/start we see that code that uses: `alignof`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`, `constexpr`, `decltype`, `noexcept`, `nullptr`, `static_assert` and `thread_local` are now reserved.

Comment: `std::auto_ptr` **has not** been removed.  It is deprecated.  Removal would have broken **far** too much code!

Comment: @Howard: and what about `export template` (though if I remember only EDG based compilers ever implemented it) ?

Comment: +1 @Howard.  It was also not part of the TR1, but officially part of the standard since the 98 version.

Comment: @Matthieu:  `export` has been removed.  The EDG team was the one to bring forward the proposal to remove it.  They are a class act.

Comment: @Klaim: While most of TR1 made it into the standard (nearly) intact, the pseudo-random number generation was modified extensively (extensively enough that I'm tempted to say "replaced" rather than "modified").

Comment: @Klaim:  Special math functions from TR1 (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1836.pdf) also did not make it into C++11, however this component did become a standard in itself: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2850.pdf .

Answer (score 2):

No, it isn't a strict superset. `extern template` and `auto`, to name a few differences..

Comment: But extern templates are new in C++0x.